# Trouble creating a measure to count results of another measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having a problem, I have a table that shows 5 columns.  The first 4 columns are actual dataset columns and the 5th is a measure.  The data table lists location IDs with and average start time and average end time by end of week.  The last column is the average variance between start and end however this is a measure and not a table column.  The location are to not have a variance of more than 15 minutes.  I need to create a measure that counts how many location made the variance goal of 15 or less for each week.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to pass the count of locations that made goal onto another calculation.  The person with the answer is a hero!!  Below is an example of the data table.  I want to be able to put the percentage out to the left of each section for the week.

[image: Table Example]

Comment: which visual are you going to use?

Comment: In Power BI I’m using the variance measure in a table and I’d like to use the compliance percentage in a card.

Comment: 1 card for each week? I can imagine 1 card for all weeks, but have no idea how to have a card for each week. You can show you percentage in rows, but it will be repeated info in rows.

Comment: or you are going to have only one card and have only one week data at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the below DAX measure the table iterator COUNTX is used to count the rows where a measure is greater than 25000000.
The count is divided by all the rows of the given group, maybe this group is your day.

IF( NOT( ISBLANK( [SalesAmount online (SUM)] ) )
, DIVIDE(
COUNTX(
CALCULATETABLE(
SUMMARIZE(
'FactOnlineSales'
, 'DimProduct'[ColorName]
)
, ALL( 'DimProduct'[ColorName] )
)
, if( [SalesAmount online (SUM)] > 25000000 , 1 , BLANK() )
)
, COUNTROWS(
CALCULATETABLE(
SUMMARIZE(
'FactOnlineSales'
, 'DimProduct'[ColorName]
)
, ALL( 'DimProduct'[ColorName] )
)
)
)
, BLANK()
)

[image]

Hopefully this provides what you are looking for^, please excuse the not formatted DAX code

Comment: GENIUS!!!   This worked flawlessly!  Thank you so much!